# Single word for "faraway places"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to know whether there is a single word for "remote, distant places" in no allegorical sense, but with a positive undertone.

Comment: These may be too allegorical for your taste, but *shangri-la, eden, heaven, paradise, promised land, nirvana, timbuktu*. And the *far side (or dark side) of the moon* is more than one word.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a more generic term, not a specific place. It might either be a singular which can have a plural form, or a collective noun.

Comment: The ends of the earth?

Comment: Would you consider Timbuktu?

Comment: I would not consider proper nouns in general since I have to use either a plural or a collective noun. _Timbuktu_ is however the most suitable proper noun among the ones in the above list.

Comment: Except that “timbuktu” doesn’t seem at all to have a positive undertone, at least not to me, although “shangri-la” does. And, I see there is a Shangri-La Luxury Hotels chain. Sounds exotic and fun! But Timbuktu Hotels? No thanks.

Comment: I suggest 'distant shores' as a generic term which is both romantic and positive, please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would not consider rural areas to have negative connotations (and faraway places are unlikely to be urban cosmopolitan), then the Australian words ***wayback*** and ***outback*** are applicable.

Another word is ***outlands***

> the outlying districts or remote regions of a country, provinces: a foreign land: *a name unknown in the outlands.*

Answer (score 3):

The *[antipodes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/antipodes?s=t)* are literally on the other side of the earth, so you could use the word to refer to remote, distant places.

The Antipodes are often used humorously to refer to Australia and New Zealand (being, as they were, on the far side of the earth from England), so *antipodes* has a positive connotation (unlike *[hinterlands](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hinterlands?s=t)*, another word I was considering suggesting, which some dictionaries define as "a place far away from busy or interesting places" -- which gives it a faintly negative connotation.)

Answer (score 1):

The term **[horizon](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/horizon)** can mean

> the range or limit of scope, interest, knowledge, etc.

It also is used to describe the far distant point at which land and sky meet. There are numerous phrases, such as *distant horizon* and *far horizon* that convey a remote location. It also tends to have a slightly positive connotation.

Comment: This is the closest to what I am thinking of, but not quite right. I am essentially looking for a word that stands for "remote places" the same way as "unknown" might stand for "unknown subjects". Or a single word which exactly means "faraway place" and can be used in its plural form. I am not sure such a word exists though :)

Answer (score 1):

**Distant shores**

**Distant shores** is a general term that implies far away lands and is romantic and positive in nature.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/distant-shores

Comment: But not the single word the question specifies, Jelila.

Comment: Feel free to post a single word answer, Edwin